# denormalized numpy arrays from postgres

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, numpy

The following query pulls out ca. 100'000 datapoints into python. Data will be plotted with matplotlib.

```
cur.execute("""SELECT  \
        loggingdb_ips_integer.ipsvalue,
        loggingdb_ips_integer.ipstimestamp,
        loggingdb_ips_integer.varid 
        FROM public.loggingdb_ips_integer
        WHERE
        (loggingdb_ips_integer.varid = 17884) OR
        (loggingdb_ips_integer.varid = 55437) OR
        (loggingdb_ips_integer.varid = 34637) OR
        (loggingdb_ips_integer.varid = 17333)
        ; """)
```

Is it more efficient to run 4 queries with each WHERE clause separately, or should I rather pull in the whole enchilada at once, and transform it into numpy array with 3 axes? And if the latter is more efficient, what is the best way to transform (normalize?) the array? Please do not jump on me because of my naivety - I am a medical doctor by training; my understanding of coding is VERY limited!

Comment: You've got two columns, and 4 possible varids. What would be the 3 axes?

Comment: They would be ips_value, ipstimestamp, and varid. I shall correct the query accordingly.

Comment: removed matplotlib flag as, while this data is destined for plotting, this question is not related to said plotting.

Comment: After you pull the data into Python, will you be grouping the data based on varid? Are there *exactly* the same number of rows for each varid?

Comment: 1. yes
2. yes (I hope). Some datapoints might theoretically be missing but they shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communicating between Python and the database is relatively slow. So usually you want to reduce the number of queries. Do as much database work as you can inside the database, and pull out only the data that you need.

These general rules of thumb lead me to guess that using 1 query would be better than 4 queries.
However, 100K rows is not very many, so it will not matter very much which method you use. Unless you're going to be running this code millions of times and need to shave off every nanosecond you can, you'll easily waste more time fretting over this than time saved just choosing one. And if you really do need that kind of performance, then you should rethink if Python is the right language for this job. As the say goes, [preoptimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

But since this will most likely not be the major bottleneck of your code, I would choose which method to use based on which code is easiest to read and maintain, not necessarily on which is fastest.

If there are *exactly* the same number of rows for each varid
then you can use a NumPy reshaping trick to coax the data into 3 axes, with the first axis corresponding to the varids (see below). In this case, making one query may be easiest as well as fastest.

If the number of rows is not exactly the same, then the code becomes a little more complicated. You would need a Python loop and a boolean NumPy mask to select the right rows. It might be easier to just make four separate queries in this case.

---

Now, out of curiosity, I decided to test my claim that 1 query is faster than 4. Maybe you'll find in here some code you can reuse.

```
import oursql
import config
import numpy as np

def create_random_data():
    connection = oursql.connect(
        host=config.HOST, user=config.USER, passwd=config.PASS,
        db='test')
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytable`'
        cursor.execute(sql)
        sql = '''CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
            `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `ipsvalue` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
            `ipstimestamp` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
            `varid` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,        
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'''
        cursor.execute(sql)
        sql = '''
            INSERT INTO mytable (ipsvalue, ipstimestamp, varid)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)'''
        N = 10**5
        args = np.empty((N, 3))
        args[:, :-1] = np.random.randint(100, size=(N, 2))
        args[:, -1] = np.tile(np.array([17884, 55437, 34637, 17333]), N//4)
        cursor.executemany(sql, args)

def one_query():
    connection = oursql.connect(
        host=config.HOST, user=config.USER, passwd=config.PASS,
        db='test')
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        varids = sorted((17884, 55437, 34637, 17333))
        sql = '''SELECT varid, ipsvalue, ipstimestamp FROM mytable
                 WHERE varid IN {}
                 ORDER BY varid, ipstimestamp, ipsvalue'''.format(tuple(varids))
        cursor.execute(sql)
        data = np.array(cursor.fetchall())
        data = data.reshape(4, -1, 3)
        arr = dict()
        for i, varid in enumerate(varids): 
            arr[varid] = data[i]
        return arr

def four_queries():
    connection = oursql.connect(
        host=config.HOST, user=config.USER, passwd=config.PASS,
        db='test')
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        arr = dict()
        varids = (17884, 55437, 34637, 17333)
        for varid in varids:
            sql = '''SELECT varid, ipsvalue, ipstimestamp FROM mytable
                     WHERE varid = ?
                     ORDER BY ipstimestamp, ipsvalue'''
            cursor.execute(sql, [varid])
            arr[varid] = np.array(cursor.fetchall())
        return arr

arr = one_query()
arr2 = four_queries()
assert all([np.all(arr[key]==arr2[key]) for key in arr])
```

---

Both `one_query` and `four_queries` returns a dict whose keys are `varid` values. As you can see, the performance is not that different, though using one query is a tad faster than four:

```
In [219]: %timeit four_queries()
1 loops, best of 3: 238 ms per loop

In [221]: %timeit one_query()
1 loops, best of 3: 195 ms per loop
```

Comment: i have the same case to fetch 100k points every few mins, it seems you are right that traditional databases are not designed to fetch all the data stored but is there any database/flat file format/library which is very specific to pull all the data stored and update few items if necessary, less than 5% or say 5000 rows in a 100k row dataset

Answer (score 1):

The query will surely be faster to run it just once. As far as 'normalizing' the data (I think you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling )

Scikit has the function [scale](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html) which works well with numpy (but you will have to group it yourself)

You can also do it in postgresql with:

```
  select
     col
     ,avg(col)
     ,stddev(col)
   from thetable
     group by col
```

and then use the z-score formula to scale the individual by joining the table:

```
 select
   (col - avg) / stddev as zscore
 from thetable as t
   join ( 
     paste the query above here
   ) as aggr on aggr.col=t.col
```

-- where col would be *varid*. It may not matter that much for performance on where you do it. Its sound more like you your problem is how to group and scale the data and what would be easiest for you.